# Why does insertion sort work only if we use while as an inner loop and doesn’t work for ” for loop”?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

I was trying to attempt a insertion algorithm question. However, I had the following question.

I wanted to nderstand why most solutions online use a nested while loop instead of a nested for loop? I thought it might have to do something with time complexity, however, both have a O(n^2) complexity.

Below I have attached the two different solutions

```
public class InsertionSort { 
// MY method
    /*Function to sort array using insertion sort*/
    // void sort(int arr[]) 
    // { 
    //     int n = arr.length; 
    //     for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) { 
    //         if(arr[i] < arr[i-1]){
    //             for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
    //                 if(arr[i] < arr[j]){
    //                     int temp = arr[j];
    //                     arr[j] = arr[i];
    //                     arr[i] = temp;
    //                 }
    //             }
    //         }
    //     } 
    // } 

// Online Solution
  
    void sort(int arr[]) 
    { 
        int n = arr.length; 
        for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) { 
            int key = arr[i]; 
            int j = i - 1; 
  
            /* Move elements of arr[0..i-1], that are 
               greater than key, to one position ahead 
               of their current position */
            while (j >= 0 && arr[j] > key) { 
                arr[j + 1] = arr[j]; 
                j = j - 1; 
            } 
            arr[j + 1] = key; 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Generally, in pretty much all programming languages, it doesn't matter whether you chose to use `for` or `while`. Under the hood, they implement the same semantics - *do something until some condition*. The difference lies in the practicality - when one is more convenient (readable, clean) over another. Also, some personal preference.

Comment: Thanks Giorgi. You are right for personal preference. I liked the for loop readability and usability better.

Comment: Your solution isn't equivalent, or as good, and it's pretty rich to claim that *all* solutions except yours use a `while` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, when developing algorithms, you choose a loop based on this:

- If the number of iterations is known, use a for-loop.
- If the number of iterations is *not* known, use a while-loop.

In Java, and other languages, you can implement the same thing using both loops. It doesn't matter if the number of iterations is known. However, it makes sense, it's more readable/logical:

- ... *for* a known starting value to a known limit do ...
- ... *while* a condition is true do ...

In [pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode), which is a way to describe an algorithm independently of implementation-details, it's often done just like that (or similar):

```
for i = 0 to n do
    ...
```

```
while condition do
    ...
```

When you look at `sort`, you can see two loops: the outer for-loop and the inner while-loop.

- The outer loop is a for-loop because `i` and `n` are known. Value `n` is known because it's given by the size of the array, which is a constant in this algorithm.
- The inner loop is a while-loop because it's not known when the condition will fail, as it depends on an array-access. You don't know the values; if you would, then you could sort the array by hardcoding some swaps.